# U-Boot: ARM: Simple delay function because of an chicken and egg problem

Tags: arm, driver, delay, u-boot

I'm running into an chicken and egg problem when modifying
(fixing) some drivers for STMicroelectronics SoC's

The problem, I will implement a timeout, when accessing some
registers. Unfortunately I cannot use the basic `mdelay()` or
higher level functions, which use this function, because
on these SoC's there isn't setup and enabled the timer before.
Also the `ARMv7-M` `SysTick` timer will not be used.

<s>I could write a simple delay loop which counts down at the
frequency from the processor speed.</s> But I think, this is
not a good idea.

Any suggestion, what I can do? I'm still new in U-Boot,
so I don't know if there a simple delay function exists.

**UPDATE:**
The reason why I currently cannot use the `SysTick` timer is, that it will be not linked in the current configuration. This is not a big problem. But the current implementation of the `SysTick` low-level source defines functions, which will be defined by another timer driver on these SoC series. So when I enable the `SysTick` in `Kconfig` I will be possible that I get a linker error with multiple definition of those functions.

Example driver with IMHO an fatal issue (missing timeout when polling a register value):
[GitHub: U-Boot: driver/clk/clk_stm32h7.c](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/master/drivers/clk/clk_stm32h7.c)

The driver currently requires a external **working** clock source
(`HSE`). No issues in the circuit are accepted by the current
implementation. Also a fixed (defined) frequency of the external
clock source.

In the probe function `stm32_clk_probe()` from the driver there
will be `configure_clocks()` called. Here are the issues.

A code snippet from `configure_clocks()`:

```
/* Switch on HSE */
setbits_le32(&regs->cr, RCC_CR_HSEON);
while (!(readl(&regs->cr) & RCC_CR_HSERDY))
    ;
```

`RCC_CR_HSERDY` will here never set by hardware, when there is no external clock source or an issue in the circuit. These leads in an endless loop. The loop of dead.

Comment: a count loop will give you a greater than some period of time which may or may not be fine, but you are not going to get some accurate time because the execution and fetching and such are not deterministic.  one compile may work but another compile the timing may be different if code not even in the same area has changed.

Comment: just use the systick timer, not sure why you wont.

Comment: and yes, libraries from chip vendors are not the best code, and need fixing from time to time or replacing.

Comment: @old_timer I can use the `SysTick` timer, but will be currently not linked in the current configuration. So I must modify `Kconfig`, but not sure if this breaks other similar SoC's. Cannot test these other boards. But I think I have no other chance, to do this.

Comment: the systick timer takes three writes to start, one time, then just read the value and subtract from the first one until you reach the time amount.  it doesnt much easier to use.  if they have already started it figure out what speed it is running and then it is just some reads to do a timed delay